Error "LimitExceeded" when trying to create an A1 instance on oracle cloud free tier
I'm trying to create a 4 CPUs 24Gb ram VM.Standard.A1.Flex instance (A1) on oracle cloud free tier to create game servers and discover the world of servers, but I'm having a lot of trouble.
When trying to create one using this script, I'm sometimes getting this output:
{
    "code": "LimitExceeded",
    "message": "The following service limits were exceeded: standard-a1-memory-count, standard-a1-memory-regional-count, standard-a1-core-count, standard-a1-core-regional-count. Request a service limit increase from the service limits page in the console. "
}

I first tried to create one from the website, but I got the infamous "out of capacity" error. Then I stumbled across oci-arm-host-capacity and let it run on a 1 CPUs  1GB ram VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro instance (micro). For a few weeks, the only output I got was
{
    "code": "InternalError",
    "message": "Out of host capacity."
}

but more recently, I sometimes get
{
    "code": "LimitExceeded",
    "message": "The following service limits were exceeded: standard-a1-memory-count, standard-a1-memory-regional-count, standard-a1-core-count, standard-a1-core-regional-count. Request a service limit increase from the service limits page in the console. "
}

I have checked in the "Limits, Quotas and Usage" tab how many resources I was using, but I'm not using any of the ones given in the output and the only boot volume I have is the 47GB one for the micro instance. I don't know if the fact that I already have a micro instance can be the cause of my problem since I'm not using any of the A1 resources.
I just realized that now, when trying to create the A1 instance on the website, I get a warning when getting higher than 3 CPUs and 19GB ram. image. I'm not sure if it was already there before.
Thanks in advance for your help.
The post might be a duplicate of this one, I'm not sure.
